# Hibernate - Retrive List of files without Blob byte array[]

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table **Uploads** that stores uploaded files as blobs and it also stores other important file information. It has the obvious fields such as

```
file_id INT
file_mime VARCHAR
file_size INT
file BYTE[]
...
```

In my Java application I have mapped this to a model class **Uploads**. The issue I am trying to solve is when I invoke my DAO from my application to get a list of file

```
 List<Uploads>.
```

I do **NOT** want to include the file byte[] array blob in the result set.

I am using a servlet to serve the files and display images so the actual file byte[] array is not needed in the result set.

When I try to do a select statement on the uploads table but exclude the file byte [] from the result set I can not cast it to a List because it is missing the file field.

How can I query my Uploads table and return a List will all of the file fields set to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the byte[] field as @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY). It will be loaded only when the getter is called.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html#fetch()

Comment: According to [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property), it requires compile-time bytecode instrumentation.